# Hide DIV based on class name contains

Tags: html, css

So i have some code that enumerates some resources and that works great. What i am having difficulty with is hiding some of those resources that contain a certain word or text. Is there a simple way I could accomplish this. With the below code.

This is the code that enumerates all my resources.

```
url = $configXml.find('resourcesProxy').attr('listURL    ajaxWrapper({ url: url, success: listResourcesSuccess });
    } else {
        showMessage('Login failed - try again');
    }
}

function loginError() { console.log('Loginled'); }

function logoffSuccess() {
    showMessage('You have logged off successfully');
    showLogonForm();
}

function showLogonForm() {
    $('#resources-container').empty();
    $('form').show();
    $('#username').select().focus();
}

function listResourcesSuccess(data) {
    var markup = '';

    resourcesData = data.resources;


    for (var i = 0; i < resourcesData.length; i++) {
        markup += generateResourceMarkup(resourcesData[i], i);
    }


    $('#resources-container').append($(markup))
                             .off('click')
                             .on('click', '.resource', null, prepareLaunch);
```

This is the embed style.css within the same html file.

```
    .resource {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    -ms-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.resource img {
        height: 42px;
        width: 42px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 6px;
        left: 21px;
    }

    .resource p {
        margin: 47px 0 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .resource:hover {
        background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

And below is the result and the resource-name, is what I would like to filter.
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qsjC.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help guys, I was actually able to figure it out. I placed the below code right at the end of the enumeration code and it worked!

```
$("div p:contains('C607'), div p:contains('T607'), div p:contains('B607'), div p:contains('M607')").parent('div').hide();
```